# Loss of PersistableUriPermission

Tags: java, android-studio, uri, android-permissions, user-permissions

My goal is to add the Uri of a video to my SQLite database, then later call the video by Uri from my app and launch it in the phone's video player.

REALLY ODD...yesterday the following code worked consistently, but now I receive an error that I do not have permission. Below is the code. Any suggestions on a better way to write this and how and why and how to make TRULY persistent the desired permission?

```
androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher<String> mGetContent = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(Uri uri) {
                my_video = uri.toString();
                getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); //Right here is where I crash
                Move move;
                move = new Move(MoveID,PositionTableID, MoveName, MoveStatus, GiY,AttackY, DefenseY, Description, internetVideoLink, my_video);
                danceDictionaryRepository.insert(move);

            }
        });
```

The error is listed as :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.android.dancedictionary/com.android.dancedictionary.Controller.PartnerDetail}: java.lang.SecurityException: No persistable permission grants found for UID 10163 and Uri content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video:634 [user 0]
```